# GAE python: how to use delete_serving_url

Tags: google-app-engine, gae-python27

1. First I put image to storage:

   ```
   import cloudstorage as gcs 
   ... 
   path = '/bucket/folder/image.jpg'
   with gcs.open(path, 'w') as f:
       f.write(data)
   ```
2. Then I get serving url:

   ```
   url = images.get_serving_url(None, filename='/gs{}'.format(self.path),
                                secure_url=True)
   ```

   Serving url generally works as expected, the thing is I'm not using blob_key, only filename (path in storage).
3. I wonder how to delete serving_url now, since sdk method only accepts blob_key

   ```
   def delete_serving_url(blob_key, rpc=None):
       """Delete a serving url that was created for a blob_key using get_serving_url.

       Args:
       blob_key: BlobKey, BlobInfo, str, or unicode representation of BlobKey of
       blob that has an existing URL to delete.
       rpc: Optional UserRPC object.

       Raises:
         BlobKeyRequiredError: when no blobkey was specified.
         InvalidBlobKeyError: the blob_key supplied was invalid.
         Error: There was a generic error deleting the serving url.
       """
   ```

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/refdocs/google.appengine.api.images#google.appengine.api.images.delete_serving_url

Comment: So `delete_serving_url` deletes the whole file on gcs right?

Comment: No, I deletes serving_url for image, so Its not accessible via this url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Using the Blobstore API with Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/#Python_Using_the_Blobstore_API_with_Google_Cloud_Storage) example shows how to obtain an equivalent blob_key for GCS:

```
blob_key = CreateFile(main.BUCKET + '/blobstore_serving_demo')
```

From that link:

> **Note:** Once you obtain a **blobKey** for the Google Cloud Storage object, you can pass it around, serialize it, and otherwise use it
>   interchangeably anywhere you can use a **blobKey** for objects stored
>   in Blobstore. This allows for usage where an app stores some data in
>   blobstore and some in Google Cloud Storage, but treats the data
>   otherwise identically by the rest of the app. (However, **BlobInfo**
>   objects are not available for Google Cloud Storage objects.)

So you should be able to generate a blobKey for your file and call `get_serving_url` and `delete_serving_url` with it.

You could also use GCS object premissions to prevent access to the file, see [Setting object permissions and metadata](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cloud-console#_permissions).

Comment: Thanks! Sounds solid, I will give it a try and then accept answer