# Store resized image on blobstore webapp2

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2, blobstore

I have resized image successfully using GAE images api now i again want to store the resized image in blob-store how can i do it kindly help. Here is the code

```
img = images.Image(blob_key=user.profile_pic)
img.resize(width=80, height=100)
img.im_feeling_lucky()
thumbnail = img.execute_transforms(output_encoding=images.JPEG)
```

if i use this code it displays the resized image but i want to store it again in blob store.

```
self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'image/jpeg'
self.response.out.write(thumbnail)
```

Comment: Blobstore does not allow you to write an image. To use Blobstore you have to upload the resized image. A better way is to use GCS (Google cloudstorage). You can use the blobstore API to store a blob in GCS and you can use the Google Cloud Storage client library to write a gcs file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save a rotated image which was stored in GAE Blobstore?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34633213/how-to-save-a-rotated-image-which-was-stored-in-gae-blobstore)

Comment: @DanCornilescu is there a way to get the serving url of resized image. So that we can display the resized image with other data.

Comment: Also via the blobstore API mentioned by @voscausa, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/39082226/4495081 for details

Comment: Actually i do not want to use the GCS.

Comment: Can we render this resized image directly on webpage.

Comment: You can use a get_serving_url in your webpage. This URL format also allows dynamic resizing and cropping with certain restrictions. Look for: google.appengine.api.images.get_serving_url

Comment: thanks @voscausa i figured it out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution after getting the serving url we can simply pass arguments in the link to perform operations on the image.

```
img = images.Image(blob_key=user.profile_pic)
url = images.get_serving_url(user.profile_pic)        
url = url + "=s80" #if i want a thumbnail
```